# Problem with vertical lines and multicolumn

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I am having some problems writing the following table:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{|c| c |c| c| c| c| c| c| c |}
\hline
Denominación  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Dimensiones} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Fibras} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Refuerzo convencional}  \\[-0pt]\cline{2-4} \cline{5-6} \cline{7-9}
 de probeta & Largo  & Ancho  & Espesor  & Nombre & Dosis & Malla  & Malla  & Marco\\[-0pt]
 & (cm) & (cm) & (cm) &  &  &  superior &  inferior & Reticulado\\[-0pt]
\midrule
A1 & \multirow{8}{*}{150} & \multirow{12}{*}{50} & \multirow{12}{*}{15}  & \multirow{4}{*}{----}  & \multirow{4}{*}{----} & \multirow{12}{*}{ACMA C139} & \multirow{4}{*}{ACMA C139}  & \multirow{2}{*}{----} \\[-0pt]
A2 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\[-0pt]
B1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \multirow{10}{*}{$1\phi 12+2\phi10$}\\[-0pt]\cline{9-9}
B2 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\[-0pt]\cline{5-5}\cline{6-6}\cline{8-8}
CA1 &  &  &  & \multirow{1}{*}{DRAMIX 3D}  &  \multirow{2}{*}{35 kg/m3}  &  & \multirow{8}{*}{----} & \\[-0pt]
CA2 &  &  &  &  65/35 BG &  &  &  & \\[-0pt]\cline{5-5}\cline{6-6}
CP1 &  &  &  & \multirow{1}{*}{EPC BarChip} & \multirow{2}{*}{6 kg/m3} &  &  & \\[-0pt]
CP2 &  &  &  &  48  &  &  &  & \\[-0pt]\cline{2-2}\cline{5-5}\cline{6-6}
DA1 & \multirow{4}{*}{80} &  &  & \multirow{1}{*}{DRAMIX 3D} & \multirow{2}{*}{35 kg/m3} &  &  & \\[-0pt]
DA2 &  &  &  & 65/35 BG &  &  &  & \\[-0pt]\cline{5-5}\cline{6-6}
DP1 &  &  &  & \multirow{1}{*}{EPC BarChip} & \multirow{2}{*}{6 kg/m3} &  &  & \\[-0pt]
DP2 &  &  &  &  48  &  &  &  & \\[-0pt]
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Especificaciones generales de las probetas a ensayar}
\label{tab:dimnesn}
\end{table}
```

As you can see, vertical lines do not appear in the upper part, and some vertical lines are not connected with the horizontal ones.

[image]

I still don't understand what is wrong with my code. 
Regards.

Comment: You use `booktabs` rules. They are not intended for use with vertical lines (packages assume, that use of vertical lines gives ugly result). Replace `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` with `\hline`, and discontinuity will disappear. And `multicolumn` erase vertical lines, sou yoou need ad in it as for example `\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Dimensiones}`. Of course it will be fare more better not to use vertical lines at all ...

Comment: From the [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) (section **2 The layout of formal tables**): "You will not go far wrong if you remember two simple guidelines at all times: 1. Never, ever use vertical rules. 2. Never use double rules". By way of example, section **1 Introduction** is just as illustrative. Read it. Read all of it.

Comment: I'm well aware that vertical lines are ugly, but in this particular case I don't see how to properly display the table without them. Guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, if you want to use vertical lines, then don't use `booktabs` and do the necessary changes as suggested by Zarko.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See which one is better suited for your needs:

[image]

For both tables I use your MWE, in which I omit all redundancies (as `[0pt]` after each end row), with packages `makecell` I try to improve look-out of column headers ...

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{array,booktabs,makecell,multirow}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage[margin=25mm,a4paper]{geometry}

    \begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{@{}*{9}{c}@{}}
    \toprule
\multirowcell{4}{Denominación\\ de probeta}  
    &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{Dimensiones} 
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Fibras} 
            &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{Refuerzo convencional}           \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-6}\cmidrule(l){7-9}
    &   \thead{Largo\\(cm)}
        &   \thead{Ancho\\(cm)}  
            &   \thead{Espesor\\(cm)}  
                &   Nombre  &   Dosis   
                    &   \thead{Malla\\ superior}  
                        &   \thead{Malla\\ inferior}   
                            &   \thead{Marco\\ Reticulado}          \\
    \midrule
A1  &   \multirowcell{8}{$\vdots$\\150\\$\vdots$} 
        &   \multirowcell{12}{$\vdots$\\50\\$\vdots$} 
            &   \multirowcell{12}{$\vdots$\\15\\$\vdots$}  
                &   \multirowcell{4}{---}  
                    &   \multirowcell{4}{---} 
                        &   \multirowcell{12}{ACMA C139} 
                            &   \multirowcell{4}{ACMA C139}  
                                &   \multirowcell{2}{---}           \\
A2 &    &   &   &   &   &   &   &                                   \\
B1 &    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \multirowcell{10}{$\vdots$\\
                                                      $1\phi 12+2\phi10$\\
                                                      $\vdots$}     \\
    \cmidrule{9-9}
B2 &    &   &   &   &   &   &   & \\
    \cmidrule{5-5}\cmidrule{6-6}\cmidrule{8-8}
CA1&    &   &   &   \multirowcell{1}{DRAMIX 3D}  
                    &   \multirowcell{2}{\SI{35}{kg/m3}}  
                        &   &   \multirowcell{8}{---}   &           \\
CA2&    &   &   &   65/35 BG 
                    &   &   &   &                                   \\
    \cmidrule{5-5}\cmidrule{6-6}
CP1&    &   &   &   \multirowcell{1}{*}{EPC BarChip} 
                    &   \multirowcell{2}{\SI{6}{kg/m3}}
                        &   &   &                                   \\
CP2&    &   &   &   48  
                    &   &   &   &                                   \\
    \cmidrule{2-2}\cmidrule{5-5}\cmidrule{6-6}
DA1&    \multirowcell{4}{$\vdots$\\80\\$\vdots$} 
        &   &   &   \multirowcell{1}{DRAMIX 3D} 
                    &   \multirowcell{2}{\SI{35}{ kg/m3}} 
                        &   &   &                                   \\
DA2&    &   &   &   65/35 BG 
                    &   &   &   &                                   \\
    \cmidrule{5-5}\cmidrule{6-6}
DP1&    &   &   &   \multirowcell{1}{EPC BarChip} 
                    &   \multirowcell{2}{\SI{6}{kg/m3}}
                        &   &   &                                   \\
DP2&    &   &   &   48  
                    &   &   &   &                                   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \caption{Especificaciones generales de las probetas a ensayar}
    \label{tab:dimnesn}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \small
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{tabular}{|*{9}{c|}}
    \hline
\multirowcell{4}{Denominación\\ de probeta}
    &   \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Dimensiones}
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Fibras}
            &   \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Refuerzo convencional}           \\
    \cline{2-9}
    &   \thead{Largo\\(cm)}
        &   \thead{Ancho\\(cm)}
            &   \thead{Espesor\\(cm)}
                &   Nombre  &   Dosis
                    &   \thead{Malla\\ superior}
                        &   \thead{Malla\\ inferior}
                            &   \thead{Marco\\ Reticulado}          \\
    \hline
A1  &   \multirowcell{8}{$\vdots$\\150\\$\vdots$}
        &   \multirowcell{12}{$\vdots$\\50\\$\vdots$}
            &   \multirowcell{12}{$\vdots$\\15\\$\vdots$}
                &   \multirowcell{4}{---}
                    &   \multirowcell{4}{---}
                        &   \multirowcell{12}{ACMA C139}
                            &   \multirowcell{4}{ACMA C139}
                                &   \multirowcell{2}{---}           \\
A2 &    &   &   &   &   &   &   &                                   \\
B1 &    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \multirowcell{10}{$\vdots$\\
                                                      $1\phi 12+2\phi10$\\
                                                      $\vdots$}     \\
    \cline{9-9}
B2 &    &   &   &   &   &   &   & \\
    \cline{5-6}\cline{8-8}
CA1&    &   &   &   \multirowcell{1}{DRAMIX 3D}
                    &   \multirowcell{2}{\SI{35}{kg/m3}}
                        &   &   \multirowcell{8}{---}   &           \\
CA2&    &   &   &   65/35 BG
                    &   &   &   &                                   \\
    \cline{5-6}
CP1&    &   &   &   \multirowcell{1}{*}{EPC BarChip}
                    &   \multirowcell{2}{\SI{6}{kg/m3}}
                        &   &   &                                   \\
CP2&    &   &   &   48
                    &   &   &   &                                   \\
    \cline{2-2}\cline{5-6}
DA1&    \multirowcell{4}{$\vdots$\\80\\$\vdots$}
        &   &   &   \multirowcell{1}{DRAMIX 3D}
                    &   \multirowcell{2}{\SI{35}{ kg/m3}}
                        &   &   &                                   \\
DA2&    &   &   &   65/35 BG
                    &   &   &   &                                   \\
    \cline{5-6}
DP1&    &   &   &   \multirowcell{1}{EPC BarChip}
                    &   \multirowcell{2}{\SI{6}{kg/m3}}
                        &   &   &                                   \\
DP2&    &   &   &   48
                    &   &   &   &                                   \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \caption{Especificaciones generales de las probetas a ensayar}
    \label{tab:dimnesn}
\end{table}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose this, using `makecell` (for line breaks in cells) and `siunitx`,  and reducing the value of `\tabcolsep`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cellalign{cc}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{@{}*{9}{c}@{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Dimensiones} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Fibras} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Refuerzo convencional} \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-6}\cmidrule(lr){7-9}
\makecell{Denominación\\ de probeta } & \makecell{Largo\\cm} & \makecell{Ancho\\(cm)} & \makecell{Espesor\\(cm)} & Nombre & Dosis & \makecell{Malla\\superior} & \makecell{Malla\\ inferior} & \makecell{Marco\\ Reticulado}\\
\midrule
A1 &
 & & & \multirowcell{4}{---} & \multirowcell{4}{---} & & \multirowcell{4}[-1em]{ACMA C139} & \multirowcell{4}{---} \\
\addlinespace
A2 \\
\addlinespace
B1 & & & & & & & & \\
\cmidrule{9-9}
B2 & \multirowcell{2}{150}\\
\cmidrule{5-6}\cmidrule{8-8}
\makecell{CA1\\ CA2}& & \multirowcell{3}{50} & \multirowcell{3}{15} & \makecell{DRAMIX 3D\\65/35 BG} & \SI{35}{kg\per m\cubed} &\multirowcell{3}{ACMA C139} & \multirow{8}{*}{---} & \\
\cmidrule{5-6}
\makecell{CP1\\CP2} & & & & \makecell{EPC BarChip\\48} & \SI{6}{kg\per m\cubed} & & & $1\phi 12+2\phi10$ \\
\cmidrule{2-2}\cmidrule{5-6}
\makecell{DA1\\DA2} & \multirow{4}{*}{80} & & & \makecell{DRAMIX 3D\\65/35 BG} & \SI{35}{kg\per m\cubed} & & & \\
\cmidrule{5-6}
\makecell{DP1\\DP2} & & & & \makecell{EPC BarChip\\48} & \SI{6}{kg\per m\cubed} & & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Especificaciones generales de las probetas a ensayar}
\label{tab:dimnesn}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]